# Generated nodejs server stub is missing routing

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I wanted to try out the code first approach with an OpenAPI spec. For testign purposes I treied the Pet Store Example from SwaggerHub.
In the generated Code I noticed, that there is no logic involving routing.

I also noticed that the code in the service folder is not even used when I run the nodejs server (changing values of example data changes nothing in the output. The API seems to run a swaggerhub server.

Do I have a missunderstanding here, what the swagger code gen does?

On the other hand the client code generation looks how I woudl expect it. Instead of creating rest requests in my client I only have to execute methods of the services.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your question, I would argue you're actually doing a "design-first" approach.

Code-first is when you have an existing codebase/service and you then create your documentation after (whether it is generated or hand written).

A design-first approach is when you create your documentation first, and THEN build out your code. If you have an OpenAPI document, and you're using Swagger codegen to create some code, then you're doing design-first.

As for your question involving routing, all Swagger codegen will do for you is generate some boilerplate code based off of your OpenAPI document. It will not add any business logic, or even route the API calls for you. It is then on you to implement all this logic after the fact.